# MediaCreationTool1909.exe - Entry Point Not Found

Tags: windows, windows-10, media-creation-tool

I'm trying to run the Media Creation Tool (1903) and I'm getting the following error:

```
MediaCreationTool1909.exe - Entry Point Not Found

The procedure entry point GetCurrentThreadId could not be located in the dynamic link library
C:\Windows\System32\apphelp.dll
```

When I click OK, I also get 4 following popups for these files: `lmsvcrt.dll`, `cryptbase.dll`, `sspicli.dll`, `RPCRT4.DLL`

My Windows 10 Pro is up to date. I downloaded the Media Creation Tool straight from Microsoft.com.

Comment: The file is corrupt.  Download the file again

Comment: I tried this with Firefox and Edge and got the same result. I was able to find version 1903 which gave me the same message.

Comment: I restarted my system and I am no longer getting this error. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

I restarted my system and it fixed my issue.